# Incorrect config to execute migration

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, maven, jpa

I use spring boot, jpa and postgreSQL. When I reinstall database and migrate table with timestamp field then this field is converted to bytea.

Spring config yml:

```
jpa:
    database: POSTGRESQL
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create-drop
    properties:
      hibernate:
        format_sql: true
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

POM:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
        <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Don't use `create-drop` you should be using flyway to manage your schema. Else a jodatime or java8 time will convert to a bytea in the database as. hibernate doesn't understand this (you need Yadira or a recent hibernate version for that).

Comment: I updated hibernate version to 5.3.2.Final and it's ok. Thank you.

Comment: Officially Spring Boot 2 (or actually Spring 5) doesn't support hibernate 5.3 (as it wasn't final at that moment). So you might run into issues.